# Accessing App code from Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, swift, remote-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

[Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) modifies the content of a remote notification before it's delivered to the user. For example if a remote notification contains an image URL, [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) can be used to fetch the image and show it in the notification content.

But how can I access actual app code in [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)? Let's say I have a `DataAccess` swift class in app code, can I access this class in [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)?

**Edit**: Some folks suggested to add app code to service extension, which is not applicable in my situation.

Comment: Have you ever tried this? I've never seen anything like this in documentation or examples. I was wondering too.

Comment: I've tried to access the app code unfortunately failed.

Comment: You would need to add the relevant source files to your extension target in Xcode

Comment: Not possible, until you add the relevant files to your service extension

Answer (score 5):

Go to the classes that you want to use in your app project. On your **File inspector** your are gonna see the **Target Membership** of your class. Check the extension's name checkbox. Then you can reuse your code.

You can also add the classes you need in the **Build Phases -> Compiled Sources** in your notification service target. The result is the same.

Comment: I am accessing Application's User Defaults Data and looping over that in my extension, but its not working for me. @alecnash

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to create a library/framework which includes your `DataAccess` class, and your app and the Notification Service Extension uses this library/framework. 
Make sure you select `Do not embed` for your framework when adding to Notification Service Extension, and select `Embed and sign` when adding it to your app.